# Spring Cloud Stream. Sourcing list of events as single events

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I use spring cloud stream for sourcing events. My problem is that I don't want to send into Source.OUTPUT list of events, but the single ones. What is the best practice to configure sourcing single events? I came up with the following solution. Is there another way to do that?

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class SharedMailboxesPoller {
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "splitterChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30000"))
  public List<NewMailEvent> pollNewMails() {
    ...
    if (!newMailEvents.isEmpty()) {
        return newMailEvents;
    } else {
        //if no events, it will send nothing
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel splitterChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
  }

  @Splitter(inputChannel = "splitterChannel", outputChannel = Source.OUTPUT)
  public List<NewMailEvent> newMailEventsSplitter(List<NewMailEvent> newEvents) {
    return newEvents;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fine; why do you question it?

Comment: Yeah, but it’s quite cumbersome. I thought there is another way, which is more compact. Maybe with java dsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the DSL will be more compact

```
IntegrationFlows.from(..., e -> e.poller(...))
                .split()
                .channel(Source.OUTPUT);
```

Or you can simply return individual events from the inbound adapter; just set `maxMessagesPerPoll` to a large number in the `poller` and the adapter will be called multiple times on each poll until it returns `null`.